# React, JS - Slack like notification system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a slack like react webapp and i want to show desktop notifications to users even when they have minimised the app. When the user clicks on the notification, i want the browser to restore , focus the tab of my react webapp and guide them appropriate section.

```
const showNotification = ({ heading, body, zoneName }) => {

  if (!Notification.permission === "granted") return;

  const notification = new Notification(heading, {
    body,
    icon: "./android-chrome-192x192.png",
  });

  notification.onclick = function (event) {
    window.open(
      `${window.location.origin}/alerts?zone=${zoneName}`,
      "_blank"
    );
    window.open('','_self').close();
  };
}
```

I am using this code but the problem is

1. I use this weird hack of creating a new _blank window and then closing the old window. because target="_self" does not restore a minimised browser window.
2. the window reloads every time when user clicks notification,
3. On mac, users can disable notification from google chrome it self in the "notification & focus" section. Is there a way to detect and tell users to allow notification for google chrome?